# Element type is invalid: expected a stringor a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am new to react and learning the same from pluralsight .I am getting this error while implementing react-router :

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Here is my piece of code --

1)main.js

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router'); 
var routes = require('./routes');
ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes}></Router>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

2)routes.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
        <Route name="app" path="/" handler={require('./components/app')}>
            <DefaultRoute handler={require('./components/homePage')} />
            <Route name="authors" handler={require('./components/authors/authorPage')}/>
            <Route name="about" handler={require('./components/about/aboutPage')}/>
        </Route>
    );

module.exports = routes;
```

3)app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var Header = require('./common/header');
var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;

var App = createReactClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <RouteHandler/> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

version --  "react-router": "^4.2.0"

Comment: your `main.js` file appears to only render an empty Router (routes are not used). Also, your `routes.js` appear to be using the v2+ API, whereas there was a significant change for the v4+ API which you are using.  You might also want to upgrade to ES6 as it will make life a bit easier when dealing with individual file/modules.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultRoute is gone as of react-router v1.0. IndexRoute is introduced instead. And since v4 IndexRoute also gone . So I guess you are using v4 React router but syntax is from version 0.1x. You should use old version of router or newer syntax.